# Kotlin `shl` not working

Tags: kotlin, bit-shift

I'm attempting to apply `shl` to an `Int` value in Kotlin:

```
val a = 1092455
println(a.toString())
println(toString(bits(one)))
println(toString(bits(one shl 16)))
println(toString(bits(one shr 16)))
```

This produces the following output:

```
1092455
0000000000010000 1010101101100111
0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0000000000000000 0000000000010000
```

As you can see, `shr` correctly results in the left most 16 bits (`0000000000010000`) being shifted to the right, however `shl` does not give the expected output (`1010101101100111 0000000000000000`).

What am I missing?

Edit: `bits` method:

```
fun bits(value: Int): BooleanArray {
    var x = value.toDouble()
    val result = BooleanArray (32)

    for (i in 31 downTo 0) {
        val d = Math.pow(2.0, i.toDouble())
        if (x >= d) {
            x -= d
            result[i] = true
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: could you please provide the `bits` implementation?

Comment: @voddan ah, the `bits` implementation didn't take signing into account. Ffs

Comment: See how I use `toString(2)` to print the numbers in my answer

Comment: @voddan yeah, that's much more elegant, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numeric values are signed in Kotlin, to when you shift left the value overflows into the negative numbers. Then the implementation of `bits` you are using is unable to print the bits correctly.

Here is how it works for me:

```
val a = 1092455
println((a shr 16).toString(2))
println((a shl 15).toString(2))
println((a shl 16).toString(2))
```

Prints:

```
 10000
 1010101101100111000000000000000
-1010100100110010000000000000000
```

That seems reasonable to me.

To fix your code use `Long` values:

```
val a: Long = 1092455
```